# How would I go about creating a simple file builder?

Tags: wordpress, file, web-applications, builder

Forgive me if this doesn't make sense but I'll do my best to explain.

I am looking into creating a piece of software/web app which will generate a package file for website themes including only the options the user would need for their project.

The best example I can think of is the underscores WordPress theme generator. But I would also like to be able to include other files. Like for example a check box that simply says "include x.js library" where if the box is checked it will include that js file or files in the folder. As well as generate the theme name, author name, theme description version number etc.

In other words I need something like underscores, that also has the option to include extra files for the development team to quickly get bespoke WordPress themes up and running whilst also including all the optional assets that we use at the firm.

Answer (score -1):

You can hold the basic logic, opening, reading, editing, closing of files in a php script that's triggered when the user submits a form.

One route to manipulate files on the server with php is to use fopen.

First enable fopen in the directory in which your files you want available for download are stored. Do this by including the following in a .htaccess file in this directory:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

In whatever script you would like triggered on form submit, you can change say the author name with something like the following (you'll obviously want to target where you're writing to, I imagine with [FSeek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)):

```
$downloadable_theme_index = 'index.php';
$handle = fopen($downloadable_theme_index, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$downloadable_theme_index);
$new_author_name = 'Abe Lincoln';
fwrite($handle, $new_author_name);
```

The logic for what files are available to download could basically be form logic that provides links to download based on user input.

Additionally, there are download manager plugins available in wordpress.